# Making sum of two variable with extra text X=

Tags: javascript, sum, sum-of-digits

Two variables A and B. I need to print sum of these two variables with extra word X=
like,

input

A=3;
B=2;

output,
X=5;

**I need (X=5;) this total answer with X=
how can I do it in javascript?? please help me.**

Comment: Where do you need to output your result? console? html?

Comment: there is no print method in javascript

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a free code site service, show us some code so we can help you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
  function printSum(a, b) {
    return "X = " + (a + b);
  }

  var a = 2;
  var b = 5;
  var output = document.querySelector("#sum");
  var sum = printSum(a, b);

  output.textContent = sum;
  console.log(sum);
```

In your html

```
<div id="sum"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Template strings can be made with
` ` symbols. For example, let's say you have variable `let name = "bob";`. You can make a template string out of it with `` console.log(`Hello, ${name}`); ``